# ul li list text goes to second line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a website using html5 and css3 but I have a problem with the the menu link.

Basically for the menu bar I am using list with a "a". But when I add the margin or padding to it part of text goes to another line as you can see below.

[image]

Here is the html code:

```
<section id="accessibility">
        <ul class="inline-content">
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

and here the css code:

```
#accessibility{
    margin-right: 2%;
}

    #accessibility ul li{
        min-width: 4rem;
        padding-left:  2%;
    }

    #accessibility ul li:first-child{
    }

    #accessibility ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: green;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: This isn't the complete css. This doesn't even have a css float to make the list horizontal. I assume other stuff is missing as well. [mcve]. You can open the developer tools (f12) and look at the style of the element to see what would be causing this (perhaps a width) and fix that, or you could likely use the css `white-space: nowrap;` or replace the space with a non-breaking one `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the "no break space" Unicode:

```
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Contact&nbsp;us</a>
```

This will keep the words on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#accessibility{
    margin-right: 2%;
}

    #accessibility ul li{
        min-width: 4rem;
        padding-left:  2%;
        display:inline-block;
    }

    #accessibility ul li:first-child{
    }

    #accessibility ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: green;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
```

```html
<section id="accessibility">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: It isn't better to use flex box? my university teacher said to use flex box.